# Is there any way to provide custom sort at time of search on ng-select?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have situation where I need to sort the data based on custom logic at time of search under ng-select. There is option for Search across multiple fields using [searchFn] but I need to sort the match result based on my custom logic.

1. Is this possible ?
2. Please share some initial ideal how this can be achieved ?

ng-select : https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? And how would you like it to be sorted?

Comment: @wentjun I want to manage sort order of item result when user search for something. so I want to manage result of search result order.

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to the search event and fire a custom function to filter your dataset and then modify the dataset that the ng-select has. You will need to manage repopulating the dropdown though if nothing is searched!

```
<ng-select (search)="onSearch($event)" [items]="data"></ng-select>

onSearch(e) {
    // Do your custom filtering here to the total dataset and then reassign.
    this.data = filtered_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using MatSort, simply fire it after clicking the search button.
i'm not sure if this would fit your request but you can see an example here: https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview